# Pandas Group By producing a series; not a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame of transactions:

```
transactions.head():

   Amount      Date of Transaction   Description  \
0   39.95      2017-03-30            Fake_Transaction_One   
1    2.39      2017-04-01            Fake_Transaction_Two      
2    8.03      2017-04-01            Fake_Transaction_Three      
3   34.31      2017-04-01            Fake_Transaction_Four    
4   10.56      2017-04-03            Fake_Transaction_Five     

       Purchase_Type        year_month  
0      Miscellaneous        2017-03  
1      tool_expense         2017-04  
2      food_and_domestic    2017-04  
3      food_and_domestic    2017-04  
4      food_and_domestic    2017-04
```

I run a groupby command on this DataFrame:

```
grouped_transactions = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'])['Amount'].sum()
```

Which produces a groupby object:

```
Purchase_Type        year_month
tool_expense         2017-04       72.49
Calendar_Event       2017-08        3.94
                     2017-12       23.92
                     2018-02       42.91
                     2018-03       10.91
```

I want to run groupby commands on this such as

```
grouped_transactions.groups.keys()
```

However I am unable to as the object is not a groupby object, but rather a Series:

```
In: type(grouped_transactions)
Out: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Looking at grouped_transactions is appears to be a groupby object, not a Series. Further it was created but running the .groupby method on a Pandas DataFrame. As such I am unsure why it is a Series.

What is the error in my understanding or my approach?

Comment: If want working with groupby object, need `g = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'])['Amount']`, but what is reason for working with groupby object? What is expected output?

Comment: If you want the groupby object, why do you immediately place `['Amount'].sum()` after it?  You're throwing away the object you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a `groupby` object, or calling an aggregation method on it, converts it to `series` or `dataframe` type objects. Best practice: if you need keys as well as aggregation, assign your `GroupBy` object to a variable and then perform multiple operations on the object.

Below are some examples.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 1], ['A', 'B', 2], ['A', 'C', 3]])

g = df.groupby([0, 1])
# <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000000007E76AC8>

keys = g.groups.keys()
# dict_keys([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')])

sums_df = g.sum()
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

sums_series_group = g[2]
# <class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy'>

sums_series = g[2].sum()
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is expected behaviour (if methods are chained like `groupby` with aggregate function) to get a `Series` or `DataFrame`.

If you need `groupby` object:

```
g = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'])
print (g)
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000000191EA5C0>
```

But if you need to convert a `MultiIndex` created by aggregation to columns:

```
df = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index()

print (df)
       Purchase_Type year_month  Amount
0      Miscellaneous    2017-03   39.95
1  food_and_domestic    2017-04   52.90
2       tool_expense    2017-04    2.39
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
grouped_transactions = transactions.groupby(['Purchase_Type','year_month'])[['Amount']].sum()
```

If you use double brackets, a list will be created, and it will be passed as an argument to the DataFrame indexing function.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question of producing a series? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Because i believe he used single bracket so grouped_transactions was a Series not a Dataframe. Correct me if i am wrong, i just started to learn. Thanks.